# Math journals in Deutsch

Tags: reference-request

I was reading construction of Hilbert 2- class fields by Franz Lemmermeyer.
Some of references to this are not in English. I wanted to read" Existence et construction des extensions galoisiennes et non-abéliennes de degré 8. J. reine angew. Math., 244, 1970, p. 37-54" but it  is in German which I do not know.

Those who have this paper in English cold you help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you certain that it's in German? That looks like French to me. Not that it makes it any better.

Comment: Looking at it, it is indeed in French. Try to browse it, it is not too difficult to read math in French (I don't know French, and I'm not native English speaker either).

Comment: ButI do not to either French or Deutch

Comment: You write "Those who have this paper in English cold you help me." as you assume it exists in English. If you know it does, please provide a reference for that. I doubt that it exists in another language than French.

Comment: Cut and paste in Google translate from French to English, You can make out what is missing by reading between the lines :)